# Bootsrap design is not showing when my netbeans project run?

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, netbeans

In netbeans when I'm running the PHP project which used bootsrap 
right click the project ==> Run 
in my browser's window it shows like this. [image]

And browser's address bar shows like  

And When I change that addres[image]s to  (lh means localhost)  by adding a '/ ' it appears like this.

I saved my project in C:\wamp\www\mobile. How can correct this situation.. Given below is my design of page..

```
       <html>
        <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Mobile Phone Repairing Records</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/datepicker.css">
    <link type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#sdate").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function doMath() {
            var in1 = document.getElementById('service_fee').value;
            var in2 = document.getElementById('sp_price').value;
            var in3 = parseFloat(in1) + parseFloat(in2);
            document.getElementById('total').value = in3;
        }
    </script>
    <style>
      .input-medium{
      height: 25px !important;
       width: 250px;
   }
        .floated{
            width: 150px;
            float: left;
            color: #3b3bf4
            }

   .clear{

              clear: both;
             }

             .font{
              color:#0066ff;
            alignment-adjust: middle;
              }
              textarea{
            width: 300px;
            min-width: 300px;
            max-width: 300px;
            min-height: 75px;
        }
        input[type="submit"] :hover, [type='reset'] :hover{    
            border: 1px solid #003333 ;
            background-color:  #003333;
            color: white;

            cursor: pointer;

        }
        .msg_sucess{
            background-color: #009933;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 500px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .msg_error{
            background-color: #ff0000;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 500px;
            font-weight: bold;

        }
        .lablefont{
            color: black;
            font-size: medium;
        }

    </style>
       </head>
        <body>
         <div class="container">
         <form action="MobilePhoneRepairing.php" method="POST" class="form-inline">
            <h1 class="font">Mobile Phone Registration</h1>          
           <div class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="span10" >
                <div class="control-group form-horizontal">
                    <p>
                        <label class="floated lablefont" for="sdate"><b>Select Date :</b></label>

                        <input type="date" name="sdate" id="sdate" class="input-medium" />
                        <br class="clear"/>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-inline">
                    <p>  
                        <label class="floated lablefont" for="model_no"><b>Model no :</b></label>
                        <input type="text" name="model_no" id="model_no" class="input-medium" placeholder="Enter Modle No" />
                        <br class="clear" />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-inline">
                    <p>  
                        <label class="floated lablefont" for="service_fee"><b>Service fee :</b></label>
                        <input type="number" name="service_fee" id="service_fee" class="input-medium" />
                        <br class="clear" />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-inline">
                    <p>  
                        <label class="floated lablefont" for="sp_name"><b>Supplier name :</b></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sp_name" id="sp_name" class="input-medium" placeholder="Enter Supplier name " />
                        <br class="clear" />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-inline">
                    <p>  
                        <label class="floated lablefont" for="sp_price"><b>Supplier price :</b></label>
                        <input type="number" name="sp_price" id="sp_price" class="input-medium"  onkeyup="doMath();"/>
                        <br class="clear" />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-inline">
                    <p>  
                        <label class="floated lablefont" for="description"><b>Description :</b></label>
                        <textarea class="textarea " name="description" rows="2" cols="12" placeholder="Enter item description" ></textarea>
                        <br class="clear" />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-inline">
                    <p>  
                        <label class="floated lablefont" for="total"><b>Total :</b></label>
                        <input type="number" name="total" id="total" class="input-medium" />
                        <br class="clear" />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-inline">
                    <p>
                        <label class="floated lablefont">  </label>

                        <input type="submit" class="btn-info btn btn-large" name="save_data" value="Save" id='savedata'  />
                        <input type="reset" class="btn-primary btn btn-large " name="reset" value="Reset Form" id='reset' />
                        <br class="clear"/>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>      


        <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: don't run directly on netbeans. just use it only as an editor. when you finished coding something go to your browser and refresh the page . For me, it worked perfectly fine rather than going to netbeans and project -> run.

Comment: @John Micah Fernandez Miguel you mean enter in browser's address bar like this.. http://localhost/mobile/MobilePhoneRepairing.php/

Comment: yes. sometimes netbeans are not compiling all your resources. I also use netbeans and I experienced it before so I just switched to the native way. when you enter the URL of your project on an address bar and just refresh it on every changes you made in your code.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the different between localhost/mobile/MobilePhoneRepairing.php and localhost/mobile/MobilePhoneRepairing.php/ ? When I'm addressed like localhost/mobile/MobilePhoneRepairing.php designs are not loading..

Comment: if that's the case then it's not a netbeans issue, it is more of an .htaccess issue. did you manage to put some .htaccess file on your project? maybe some URL rewriting codes were written onto it.

Comment: I don't think so.. :( can you give me an example.. All I ever added is css, javascript files from downloaded from bootsrap..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42823/discussion-between-john-micah-fernandez-miguel-and-dilini)

Comment: thanks @John Micah Fernandez Miguel

Comment: Problem is not in netbeans but paths to your css files. Looks like your `css` folder is inside `mobile`